# Adding DISTRO_FEATURES to image bitbake recipe

Tags: yocto, openembedded

I've added support for virtualization in my yocto image by adding the following to my local.conf file:

```
DISTRO_FEATURES_append= " virtualization"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " docker docker-contrib"
```

(as per instructions in https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-virtualization/tree/README).
This is working fine, so now I'm trying to create a new image bitbake recipe to move this into so that I can build both with and without virtualization. I've added an image recipe which is as follows (relevant parts):

```
DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " virtualization"
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL = " docker docker-contrib"
inherit core-image
```

but that doesn't work - bitbake now complains that:

> WARNING: You have included the meta-virtualization layer, but
>   'virtualization' has not been enabled in your DISTRO_FEATURES. Some
>   bbappend files may not take effect. See the meta-virtualization README
>   for details on enabling virtualization support.

So it seems that DISTRO_FEATURES is not valid in the image bitbake. Is that the case and if so what is the proper way to add an image to my build that requires an additional DISTRO_FEATURES while leaving the existing images alone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, you can't set DISTRO_FEATURES in a recipe.  It controls the features of the distro, so only makes sense in a distro configuration or other top-level configuration file such as local.conf.

Comment: is there a top-level configuration that I can put this into in order to pick it up for some image recipes but not others? I'm trying to find a way to do this that does not involve having 2 build directories, one for each image (which is what I currently have). This works in the machine layer, but there doesn't seem to be a way to specify different (sub)machines for different images.

Comment: Distro features are by definition distro-wide.  Why can't you enable virtualisation at a distro level in DISTRO_FEATURES but then only install docker in the images where you want docker?

Comment: yes I can do that and I'm guessing that's the way I'll end up going. My only concern is that having it enabled for both images will cause an increase in size in the image that does not use virtualization.

Comment: You'll have to look at what the virtualisation feature does to determine that.  It's perfectly possible that the final image size difference is negligible.