# changing kernel configuration for different recipes based on a external variable in yocto

Tags: yocto, bitbake

How can I change kernel configuration based on the recipe ?.

In my case , want to build kernel package for two different recipes ( a prod and dev version) and  have to disable some configuration for production.

I have separate recipes for prod and dev images, but now I cannot distinguish between prod and dev in the kernel-package recipe.

I have tried DISTRO_FEATURE  , but it didnt work as we cannot set DISTRO_FEATURE in a recipe.
have referred this link [Adding DISTRO_FEATURES to image bitbake recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53839166/adding-distro-features-to-image-bitbake-recipe)

Any suggestions please?

nan

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, thats not how it works. One recipe cannot affect another, thats why you cannot set `DISTRO_FEATURES` in a recipe. So you have to set your desired change somewhere else. A suitable place might be a distint `DISTRO` for dev puposes, that just overwrites or adds some things to the production one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion,I am looking for an option other than creating a distinct Distro.